# How to use a custom class as a type variable for an Iterator?

Tags: java, generics, implementation

I have the following code using generics:

```
Set membersKeySet = membersList.keySet();
Iterator<DoubleKey> membersItr = membersKeySet.iterator();
while(membersItr.hasNext()){
    DoubleKey<Integer, Integer> dk =  membersItr.next();
}
```

Eclipse tells me that "Set is a raw type. References to generic type <E> should be parametrized". DoubleKey is also a Generic class. What I understand is that the .iterator() method doesn't assure that the DoubleKey Class has been passed with the same parameter types. I tried typecasting but it doesn't work. How can I pull this off? Thanks!

P.S. I'm still n00b inusing Generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objects stored in the set are instances of `DoubleKey<Integer, Integer>`, then the code should look like this :

```
Set<DoubleKey<Integer, Integer>> membersKeySet = membersList.keySet();
Iterator<DoubleKey<Integer, Integer>> membersItr = membersKeySet.iterator();
while(membersItr.hasNext()){
    DoubleKey<Integer, Integer> dk =  membersItr.next();
}
```

Comment: Yeah! I just did it. Haha. I didn't realized that I hadn't specified the type variables in Set. Thanks Stackoverflow folks!

Answer (score 0):

You should define type of the keyset.

```
Set<DoubleKey> membersKeySet = membersList.keySet();
```

Could you please provide `memberList` definition to provide the full picture?

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on what `membersList` is, I'd expect this to be the solution:

```
Set<DoubleKey> membersKeySet = membersList.keySet();
```

If `membersList` is *also* declared using a raw type, it becomes trickier... but we'll cross that bridge when you've checked whether that's all you need :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you give, it looks like membersList is actually a map of some sort.  So, in order to get the compile time type safety of generics, membersList should be defined appropriately, something like

```
Map<DoubleKey, Object> membersList = new HashMap<DoubleKey, Object>();
Set<DoubleKey> membersKeySet = membersList.keySet();
```

With that, your iterator should work as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use the compact for-loop notation:

```
while(DoubleKey<Integer, Integer> dk: membersList.keySet()) {
}
```

And if you are using `DoubleKey&lt;Integer, Integer&gt;` all over the place, consider making it a class all on its own:

```
class IIKey extends DoubleKey<Integer, Integer> {}
```